# how do i call a procedure with 2 out parameter in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

How do i call a procedure with 2 out parameter in hibernate? Here is my procedure:

`PROCEDURE get_my_prc(IN p_id bigint unsigned, OUT p_total_avail int, OUT p_total_wl int)`

How doI call this proc in hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

Try native SQL.

```
String sql = "SELECT get_my_prc(:in1, :in2, :in3) FROM dual";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("in1", new Object()); // Replace new Object() with whatever you need
query.setParameter("in2", new Object()); // Replace new Object() with whatever you need
query.setParameter("in3", new Object()); // Replace new Object() with whatever you need
List results = query.list();
```

More info in this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm

EDIT:

Also remember that you have to modify the native SQL query to the database you are using to. The one provided by me in the example might not work. Just use standard query that works for you if you run it on database directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, have you tried this ?. i am using my sql and i tired with native sql and i got the error Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE. expected 3, got 1.

Comment: 2nd and 3 rd are not input parameter it is out param. with in put param i am able to execute query.

Answer (score 0):

just cal normal way but store response out param 
in Object[] and we can also get multiple response value in Onject[]

```
Object[] respnseCode = (Object[])session.createSQLQuery(
"CALL myProcedure_only_in_parms (:in_Id)")
.setParameter("in_id", 123);
List result = query.list();
sysout("out_Id"+respnseCode[0]);
sysout("out_message"+respnseCode[1]);
```